# Cannot access variable in function, but I can get it outside

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3

I have a variable

```
setup: {
  const items = ref<basicPokemon[]>([]);
}
```

But i can't seem to get access to it in my function. I can however access it inside the 'methods' part, not inside the function. What am I doing wrong?

```
methods: {

this.items //this works

 let response =  axios({
              url: 'https://stoplight.io/mocks/appwise-be/pokemon/57519009/pokemon',
              method: 'get',
              timeout: 8000,
              headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              }})
              .then(data => data.data.forEach(function(pok: basicPokemon){
                  try{
                    this.items.value.push(pok); //here I cannot access the variable
                
                  }
                  catch(err){
                    //todo error handling
                        console.log(err)
                  }
                }))
}
```

Comment: declare outside of `axios` call `let myvar = this.items` and try to use `myvar` inside of your `axios` call.

Comment: `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', }})` is nonsense. Your request body isn't JSON. You don't have a request body in the first place.

Comment: I did what Rafael said: `let list = ref<basicPokemon[]>(this.items)`
Seems to work!